# How to make battleship boat spawner in java?

Tags: java

Essentially, it is my big grade 12 code project in java to make a battleship. I have most of the mechanics finished I just am struggling with a random boat generator. It seems to almost work sometimes with variation in sizes, however, I often find random clumps that do not resemble the boats I want. Basically, each spot on a 2d grid is an object that has an int variable named status. If status=0, it is a water spot. if status=1, it is a boat spot. Any errors in my code or is there possibly a better way? Thank you for the help I really appreciate it :)

Haven't done any other method because nothing else has come to my head.

```
void addBoat(int x) {
  int c=floor(random(4));//picks a random direction
  int tx, ty;//target location in array
  tx=floor(random(xs));//xs is x size of the array
  ty=floor(random(ys));//ys is the y size of the array
  for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
    //paramaters for conditions
    if (c==0 && tx>=x-1 && sqr[tx-i][ty].status==0) {
      sqr[tx-i][ty].status=1; //to the left of the target block, status is whether it is water or boat. water is status=0, boat is status=1.
    } else if (c==1 && tx<=xs-x && sqr[tx+i][ty].status==0) {
      sqr[tx+i][ty].status=1; //to the right of the target block
    } else if (c==2 && ty>=x-1 && sqr[tx][ty-i].status==0) {
      sqr[tx][ty-i].status=1; //above the target block
    } else if (c==3 && ty<=ys-x && sqr[tx][ty+i].status==0) {
      sqr[tx][ty+i].status=1; //below the target block
    } else {
      c=floor(random(4));
      i=0;
      //if position is not possible, run again
    }
  }
}

void makeBoat() {
  addBoat(2);
  addBoat(3);
  addBoat(3);
  addBoat(4);
  addBoat(5);
}
```

I want boats to be the proper size and either vertical or horizontal, however I usually just get strange clumps.

Comment: Does `random()` work properly?  Also, I'd choose better var names.  Why not rename `c` to `direction` and `x` to `boat_size` for example?  If you have to add comments, it means your vars are not well named. :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like you are placing your boat pieces before checking whether your boat can be fully placed. The moment it detects it can't properly place the boat it starts over without deleting the already generated pieces. Another thing is that you don't seem to have anything in place for the case that it is impossible to place a boat at a chosen starting position, at which point it probably runs into an infinite loop.

All in all, I'd recommend you to first generate a set of a position, a direction and a length, then check whether this is a valid boat placement and only then place it (or generate a new set), i.e. split it up into three methods. There's still a slim chance of infinite loops if boats are generated such that it is impossible to place the next one so you may want to have some checks in place to prevent that (maybe deleting the state completely and starting over if it does >10,000 attempts for a single boat or something).

You should also use enums instead of integers for your states/directions to make it more readable. You could also use boolean values for your states if they only store whether there's water or a boat.